# C++ - Can't compile functions of <cstdio> at ubuntu17.10 with g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu6) 4.8.5

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I am new to this forum and have the following question. 
I recently installed ubuntu 17.10 (artful). My compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu6 
(output of g++ --version). Unfortunately i cannot chose a newer compiler version, due to a specific framework i use. I wrote the following minimal example:

```
//test.cpp
#include <cstdio>
int main ()
{
  char buffer [100];
  int cx;

  cx = std::snprintf ( buffer, 100, "The dhalf of %d is %d", 60, 60/2 );


 }
```

When i try to compile this via

```
g++  -std=gnu++11 -o test test.cpp
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:13: error: ‘snprintf’ is not a member of ‘std’
    cx = std::snprintf ( buffer, 100, "The half of %d is %d", 60, 60/2 );
         ^
test.cpp:8:13: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdio:42:0,
             from test2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:340:12: note:   ‘snprintf’
extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
```

Has anybody an idea why this is happening? thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using the alternative, that compiler suggested to you?

Comment: What happens if you invoke just `snprintf` instead of `std::snprintf`?

Comment: @Max Graf  Try to use ::snprintf instead.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you change `-std=gnu++11` or omit it?

Comment: @Daniel Langr, if i just use snprintf it works. The problem is, i need to include armadillo, which uses std::snprintf. The problem is not only with the std::snprintf function, but also with other functions... I already figured out, that it has to do something with the _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_DYNAMIC (can be found in cstdio header). The section beyond this macro is greyed out in eclipse  : /

Comment: @MaxGraf And do you need `-std=gnu++11`? Does it work with `-std=c++11`? This might be related: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Backwards-Compatibility.html#Backwards-Compatibility

Comment: @harper: i tried -std=gnu++11 already, it changes nothing.

Comment: Sry i meant that i tried it with both options, c++11 and gnu++11, the same behavior in both cases....

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/g/oYyA7u

Comment: The strange thing is, i tried it on another system where the output of g++ --version is Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 , there it worked...

Comment: Also cannot reproduce with Wandbox and g++ 4.8.5: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FGMMINbRCsT97GEr

Comment: It should work, it seems that the `<cstdio>` header file it non conforming for some reason. Put `namespace std {  using :: snprintf;}` right after `include <cstdio>` and try if that works.

Comment: @Michael Walz, if i write                                                                                          #include <cstdio>
    namespace std { using :: snprintf;}, it works

Comment: Also compare the <cstdio> header files from both systems (the one where it works and the one where it doesn't)

Comment: @MichaelWalz You should make an answer from your comment, nice solution. I just wonder whether this does not break rules about extending the `std` namespace.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes it does break the rule about not extending namespace std. That was not meant as an answer, but as a diagnostic step.

Comment: The headers are identical, but i see that on the system where it doesnt work, the whole section included in if condition  #if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 (line 142 for me) is greyed out in eclipse. On the system where it works, this section is white.

Comment: as a temporary fix try to add this above the include: `#define _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCSTOF 1` `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 1`

Comment: WIth this temporary fix it works, thanks. But is there a solution to solve this issue permanently?I need to compile a big project with many different files.

Comment: You could add the defines to your global compiler flags for the project with the -D flag: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: @DanielLangr no, this is not the right way to solve it. PaulR's comment (the one just above this one) is a better solution.

Comment: I suppose the default compiler options are different on both computers for some reason, do `gcc -Q -v yourcpp.file.cxx` on both computers and compare the outputs. [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138335/gcc-4-3-3-compiler-options-enabled-by-default) may help